# "page not found" when trying to add image node to drupal 6

Tags: image, drupal

I get this error recently, after I migrated my site to a new server and upgraded from drupal 6.20 to 6.22. Whenever I try to add an image node (or my other custom-defined node in which there is an image upload field) I end up with a "page not found" page. Previously created nodes are displayed without any issue.

All the installed modules are exactly as before and are updated to their latest version. 
I really appreciate your hints.

Comment: Is this a CCK Image field? Is the error happening when you try to open the node edit form or after you submit the edit form?

Comment: Yes it's a CKK Image filed. The error occurs when I try to create a image content and also whenever I try to edit an existing node of that type.

Comment: It may worth mentioning that I have no problem uploading images through the text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the culprit in the status report:

> The
>   sites/all/modules/image/image.imagemagick.inc
>   file must be copied to includes in
>   order for the ImageMagick image
>   toolkit to function

Copying the file solved the issue. Silly me!